# How would I crack a software that has Xor encryption

Tags: c++, c, x64dbg, x86-64, xor

So, before you shout at me to go on google I would just like to say I am new to reverse Engineering. Like I have been doing it for a hour. So, I was doing a bunch of crackmes.one using the search all string references and changing it to always say yes. But then I run into this software: https://crackmes.one/crackme/63445b9533c5d4425e2cd7cf I treat it like any other use die and see that it is unpacked. But when I search for the string nothing pops up. I am guessing this is because of the Xor encryption. How would I decrypt software (if that's the right term)? and for future cases when I don't get told the encryption method how would I be able to tell?